# Multiple export using google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Not sure whether this is the right place to ask but I am currently trying to run a dataflow job that will partition a data source to multiple chunks in multiple places. However I feel that if I try to write to too many table at once in one job, it is more likely for the dataflow job to fail on a HTTP transport Exception error, and I assume there is some bound one how many I/O in terms of source and sink I could wrap into one job?

To avoid this scenario, the best solution I can think of is to split this one job into multiple dataflow jobs, however for which it will mean that I will need to process same data source multiple times (once for which dataflow job). It is okay for now but ideally I sort of want to avoid it if later if my data source grow huge.

Therefore I am wondering there is any rule of thumb of how many data source and sink I can group into one steady job? And is there any other better solution for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Dataflow service description of structuring user code](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc):

> The Dataflow service is fault-tolerant, and may retry your code multiple times in the case of worker issues. The Dataflow service may create backup copies of your code, and can have issues with manual side effects (such as if your code relies upon or creates temporary files with non-unique names).

In general, Dataflow should be relatively resilient. You can [Partition](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Partition) your data based on the location you would like it output. The writes to these output locations will be automatically divided into bundles, and any bundle which fails to get written will be retried.

If the location you want to write to is not already supported you can look at [writing a custom sink](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sinks). The docs there describe how to do so in a way that is fault tolerant.

There is a bound on how many sources and sinks you can have in a single job. Do you have any details on how many you expect to use? If it exceeds the limit, there are also ways to use a single custom sink instead of several sinks, depending on your needs.

If you have more questions, feel free to comment. In addition to knowing more about what you're looking to do, it would help to know if you're planning on running this as a Batch or Streaming job.

Comment: thanks ben, i might expecting around say 4 source but around 60 ~ 200 output sink in one dataflow job, for which i am not sure whether it might be a little too many or not. The location is supported as i expect i am either using gcs or bq. the data source is all static (so batch dataflow jobs) to begin with, although in the future it might be possible to hook up a streaming source but it is just optional

Answer (score -1):

Our solution to this was to write a custom GCS sink that supports partitions. Though with the responses I got I'm unsure whether that was the right thing to do or not. [Writing Output of a Dataflow Pipeline to a Partitioned Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801785/writing-output-of-a-dataflow-pipeline-to-a-partitioned-destination/34820424#comment57644303_34820424)